# Using foreach loop to increment variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to loop these variables below (item_name, quantity and amount)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostToPaypal", "ShoppingCart"))
{

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="@item.Product.Title"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="@item.Count" />
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="@item.Product.Price"/>   
    }
}

    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Pay with PayPal" />
}
```

**I do not know how to merge these two for loops. 
And i do not know how to use the "int i .." in the "input type field"**

Could somebody please explain to me **(in code)** how i can achieve this?

ShoppingCartController;

```
   public ActionResult PostToPaypal(string item_name, string quantity,string amount)
     {
        ESpiceHerbs.Models.PayPal paypal = new Models.PayPal();

        paypal.cmd = "_xclick";
        paypal.business = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessAccountKey"];
        paypal.no_shipping = "1";
        bool useSandbox = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseSandBox"]);
        if (useSandbox)
            ViewBag.actionURL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        else
            ViewBag.actionURL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

        paypal.cancel_return = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CancelURL"];
        paypal.@return = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReturnURL"];//+"&PaymentId=1"; you can append your order Id here
        paypal.notify_url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotifyURL"]; // +"?PaymentId=1"; to maintain database logic 

        paypal.currency_code = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CurrencyCode"];

        paypal.item_name = item_name;
        paypal.quantity = quantity;
        paypal.amount = amount;
        return View(paypal);
    }
```

PayPal.Model

```
    public class PayPal
    {
    public string cmd { get; set; }
    public string business { get; set; }
    public string no_shipping { get; set; }
    public string @return { get; set; }
    public string cancel_return { get; set; }
    public string notify_url { get; set; }
    public string currency_code { get; set; }
    public string item_name { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
}
```

And PostToPayPal.cshtml

```
    <form id="frm" action="@ViewBag.actionURL">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cmd)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.business)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.no_shipping)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.@return)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cancel_return)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.notify_url)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.currency_code)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item_name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.quantity)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.amount)
    </form>
```

I have referenced the PayPal method from http://www.arunrana.net/2012/01/paypal-integration-in-mvc3-and-razor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you might need is this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostToPaypal", "ShoppingCart"))
{

    for (int i=0; i<Model.CartItems.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CartItems[i].Product.Title)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CartItems[i].Count)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CartItems[i].Product.Price) 
    }

<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Pay with PayPal" />
```

}

And then on the `PostToPaypalAction`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostToPaypal(MODELTYPEHERE[] model)
    {
        //processing here
    }
```

Comment: I tried your method. No errors being returned. But when i checkout to PayPal, no values are being passed. Could you be more specific as to what I should do in the controller, please? Thanks!!

Comment: @Mohamed Azlan - Could you post the model you are using and the controller action in your question so that I may better understand what the problem might be.  Thanks.

Comment: I have added the Controller, Model and Cshtml page by editing the post. Thanks you for looking into this.

Comment: @Mohammed Azlan - You displayed a collection of items in the form but you are only trying to bind to a single item in the action which is why nothing was binding.  Thats why you need to bind to a collection of some sort instead. Instead of `PostToPaypal(string item_name, string quantity,string amount)` I think you should use `PostToPaypal(CartItems model)` instead.

Comment: After replacing with    (CartItems model) I get this error;

The type or namespace name 'CartItems' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Mohammed - Then add a reference to it at the top of your controller file.  i.e. using ... I'm assuming CartItems exists as your referenced it in your view model.

Comment: @@Dangerous thanks for your help. I finally got it done with a slightly different approach. Nevertheless, thank you for your time! Appreciate it.